# BIOS doesn't recognize XMP profile

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, motherboard, bios

Build

- Motherboard: Asus Sabertooth Z87 LGA 1150
- RAM: G.SKILL Sniper Series 32GB 40-Pin DDR3 Model F3-2400C11Q-32GSR
- CPU: Intel Core i7-4770K Haswell LGA 1150 84W BX80646I74770K
- SSD: Samsung 850 PRO 256GB Internal SATA III
- Power Supply: Corsair Memory HXi HX1200i ATX12V
  -GPU: EVGA 03G-P3-1591-AR GeForce GTX 580 (Fermi) Hydro Copper 2 3072MB 384-bit

**The Problem**

After swapping out the G.SKILL Sniper Series 8GB (240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 F3-12800CL9D-8GBSR, with G.SKILL Sniper Series 32GB 40-Pin DDR3 Model, the BIOS did not activate the XMP profile and later did not recognize it in a SPD profile.

**What I've done**

After clearing the CMOS, the BIOS stopped recognizing the SSD, with it still not recognizing the new RAM. However, when I put back the old G.SKILL 1600 sticks, they were recognized. I have repeatedly cleared the CMOS, have taken out the battery, tried different SSDs (none of them recognized).

**Additional Details**
The SSD is recognized on my other computer. The G.SKILL website also lists the motherboard as compatible and part of its QVL. All of my HDDs (5) are being recognized by the BIOS. I've also updated the BIOS

Comment: why do you care about the XMP profile? Is is often unstable as hell and give you no real improvement only stability issues. Don't use this crap.